# How to get build job timeout duration for VSTS free subscription via API?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

VSTS build task is getting cancelled in free subscription due to 30 minute fixed build time. I need to display a console message to the user if he is using the vsts free subscription. Is there an API to get this information? Is possible to get this info through vso-node-api library?

Comment: Don't find the way to get timeout through vso-node-api. Just find jobTimeoutInMinutes member in BuildDefinition (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/contracts/builddefinition)

Comment: JobTimeoutInMinutes is set to 60 by default in the free subscription, but it get cancelled in 30 minutes when executing the build. Ill try to get the value from build contracts and update you.

Comment: Yes, I get 60 too. Seems not a related API to get that timeout.

Comment: Yep, I also got the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any API to get this information. As an alternative way, you can display a warning message to remind the user when they use Hosted Pool for the build.

You can use VSTS Node API to get the pool name of the build:

```
let buildid: number = 1;
let projectname: string = "Project";
let build: bi.Build = await vstsBI.getBuild(buildid, projectname);
console.log(build.queue.name);
```

For the buildid and project, get it from the build environment variable.

Comment: Thanks Eddie, Is there an API to identify whether user is using hosted pool?

Comment: Or just display a fixed warning message?

Comment: @BandR When do you want to display this message? In the build definition settings or during a build process?

Comment: As a log entry during the build process.

Comment: @BandR A simple way is getting the environment variable "AGENT_MACHINENAME" during the build process, the hosted build agent is usually named as "TASKAGENTX-XXXX".

Comment: @BandR And if you want to use VSTS Node API, you can use getBuild() method to get the current build. And the pool name is included in the information. See my updated answer for details.